# mGWT State management

Tags: android, gwt

During testing of mgwt application in emulator, if we suddenly stop and go to home page in emulator and start the application again, it will directly load the last page where we were wokring. Why it is not resetting it to the first page? 
In GWT on module function, I am always loading the default place. I need to explicitly go and remove data and then start application to proceed.
How to overcome this problem programatically? Do we have any reference for it? I have not used gwt-phonegap, it is just mgwt with GWTp framework application.

Answer (score 0):

I think your application isn't stopped. I think it is running in background. If you bring it back to front, it shows the same screen again.